# When is the AS keyword required?

Tags: postgresql, sql-standard

In the following statement (PostgreSQL 11):

```
=> SELECT c cost FROM tt;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "cost"
LINE 1: SELECT c cost FROM tt;
```

I get an error. Adding parenthesis around the field expression doesn't help (`SELECT (c) cost FROM tt;`). But adding the `AS` keyword fixes it.

```
=> SELECT c AS cost FROM tt;
 cost 
------
    1
...
```

I realize that `cost` is a keyword, but my impression is that the `AS` keyword is optional.

From a language perspective, why is the `AS` keyword required (or helpful) here? Is the PostgreSQL behavior here standard or documented somewhere?

Are there any other cases when the `AS` keyword is required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html):

> In the SQL standard, the optional key word AS can be omitted before an
>   output column name whenever the new column name is a valid column name
>   (that is, not the same as any reserved keyword). PostgreSQL is
>   slightly more restrictive: AS is required if the new column name
>   matches any keyword at all, reserved or not

`cost` is a keyword, so `as` is required.

Also:

> Recommended practice is to use AS or double-quote output column names,
>   to prevent any possible conflict against future keyword additions.

... but my preference is to not quote & instead be consistent with using `as`.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6473bbb7df2aa9e074dcc0498d6681e5

Comment: Also, using `AS reserved_keyword` may lead into all kinds of trouble: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=763677a11eab502df620cca86013717d

Comment: And avoid using reserved words as table or column names.

Comment: @Colin'tHart, while I agree it can be difficult to foresee what might be a reserved word in the future. Personally, I try to use as descriptive identifiers as possible, i.e. course_code instead of just code.  Not sure why but I genuinely dislike quoted identifiers. As for as I would like to use it more than I do in reality. I especially remember a query that I could not get my head around: "select ... from T `outer union` select ... from ..." It took a while figuring out what the outer union meant;-)

Comment: Worth adding ([like the manual does](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-select.html#id-1.9.3.171.10.5)): `In FROM items, both the standard and PostgreSQL allow AS to be omitted before an alias that is an unreserved keyword. But this is impractical for output column names, because of syntactic ambiguities.` Hence my rule of thumb: never omit the `AS` keyword for column aliases, but omit it at will for table aliases. (And *never* use reserved keywords as identifiers.)